# Can you set a variable inside a mixin in LESS CSS?

Tags: less

I understand LESS doesn't have if/else structure and instead relies on guarded mixin statements.  It doesn't appear to be able to set a LESS CSS variable inside of a mixin though.

Anyone have an idea of how I could implement something to the effect of.

```
if( ispercentage( @height ) {
  @height: "1024px";
}

// Calculations dependent on @height
@textAreaHeight = 0.5 * @height;
@buttonHeight = 0.2 * @height;
```

I've looked at several other stackoverflow questions including: 
[LESS CSS - Setting variable within mixin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9489892/less-css-setting-variable-within-mixin)

Comment: You should use : instead of the = sign, but you already knew that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it can be done. There was one bug that needed to be worked around.

**Example LESS Code**

```
//Set up guarded mixins
.setHeight(@h) when (ispercentage(@h)) { 
   @height: 1024px;
}

.setHeight(@h) when not (ispercentage(@h)) { 
   @height: @h;
}

//set up main height
@mainHeight: 50%;
body { height: @mainHeight;}

//call it by itself to make global
//.setHeight(@mainHeight); <-this failed (appears to be a bug)
.setHeight(50%); // <-this worked

.subsection { height: @height; /* just to show it is setting it */}

//use it for other globals
@textAreaHeight: 0.5 * @height;
@buttonHeight: 0.2 * @height;

textarea { height: @textAreaHeight}
button { height: @buttonHeight}

//override it locally
body.fixedHeight {
    .setHeight(300px);
    @textAreaHeight: 0.333 * @height;
    height: @height;
    textarea { height: @textAreaHeight}
}
```

**Example CSS Output**

```css
body {
  height: 50%;
}
.subsection {
  height: 1024px; /* just to show it is setting it */
}
textarea {
  height: 512px;
}
button {
  height: 204.8px;
}
body.fixedHeight {
  height: 300px;
}
body.fixedHeight textarea {
  height: 99.9px;
}
```

Comment: @blak3r--I [submitted the issue](https://github.com/cloudhead/less.js/issues/878) with passing of the variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a mixin that is "guarded" by the type, e.g.

```
.doHeightSet(@height) when ispercentage(@height) {
   .doheightSet(1024px)
}

.doHeightSet(@height) when not ispercentage(@height) {
   // Calculations dependent on @height
   @textAreaHeight: 0.5 * @height;
   @buttonHeight: 0.2 * @height;

   /* use variables here */
}
```

Sorry, I don't have time to try this out, so I may have made a syntax mistake.

**edit** corrected syntax.

Comment: I don't think you can set a variable inside a mixin though.  Can you?  I tried playing around with it and couldn't get anything to compile.