# Accessing a less variable from a separate mixin

Tags: variables, less

Basically I want to access the variable @b from a mixin for use elsewhere. an example of what I am trying to do is as follows, but this does not work:

```
.mixin (@x:@x, @y:@y, @z:@z) {
       @b: (@x + @y) / @z; 
}

.item (@x:@x, @y:@y, @z:@z) {
       .mixin (@x, @y, @z);
       margin-left: @b;
 }

.item2 (@x:@x, @y:@y, @z:@z) {
       .mixin (@x, @y, @z);
       margin-right: @b;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated and thank you in advance.

Jason

Comment: Is there anything more to `.mixin` or is it just being used to calculate `@b`?

Comment: yeah there is quite a bit more but i have simplified the code which is causing the problems to this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously, your main issue here is variable scoping. Based off [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11405742/can-you-set-a-variable-inside-a-mixin-in-less-css/11647477#11647477), there are cases where you can set a variable in a mixin and have it usable outside that mixin, but as that answer shows, an apparent bug in LESS prevents that variable from being set by passing in other variables (which is what you need here). NOTE: supposedly that bug is fixed, so perhaps the latest download of the LESS compiler may solve your issue; I do know that the online compilers I normally test in still do not allow this type of setting of variables.

So here is another suggested alternative: create what you need as a nested parametric mixin within your `.mixin` which makes `@b` fully accessible.

So this **LESS**

```
@x: 3;
@y: 3;
@z: 2;

.mixin (@x:@x, @y:@y, @z:@z, @bProp: null) {
       //all your other mixin code

       @b: (@x + @y) / @z;

       //set up pattern matching for props
       //that need @b

       .prop(null) {} //default none
       .prop(ml) {
          margin-left: @b;
       }
       .prop(mr) {
          margin-right: @b;
       }
       //call the property
       .prop(@bProp);
}

.item (@x:@x, @y:@y, @z:@z) {
       //this is a pure default of .mixin()
       .mixin (@x, @y, @z); 
 }

.item1 (@x:@x, @y:@y, @z:@z) {
       //this is set up to call the margin-left pattern
       .mixin (@x, @y, @z, ml);
 }

.item2 (@x:@x, @y:@y, @z:@z) {
       //this is set up to call the margin-right pattern
       .mixin (@x, @y, @z, mr);
}

.item(); 
.item1(); 
.item2(6,6,3);
```

Produces this **CSS** (which obviously would be used actually inside a selector, but I think you get the point).

```
//note that nothing is produced for .item() because it
//defaults to no extra properties other than the base .mixin()
margin-left: 3;
margin-right: 4;
```

Comment: thanks that does seem to have solved it, but wow that is a crazy amount of code to get it to work. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1937392: really, it is just slightly more code; just moved the code from the `item` mixins to the `mixin` mixin. I added an extra `item` in my example just to show the working of it.

Comment: my apologies have realised that the way you are coding actually is more efficient and prevents duplication even further. Thanks again.

Comment: @user1937392: Great. Don't forget to "accept" this answer if it met your needs and/or "upvote" the answer if it was helpful.